# Problem on getting images use generateCGImagesAsynchronouslyForTimes

Tags: objective-c, ios

I want to get some images from a movie and make a gif. What I have done is use a imagePickerController to take a movie, and then I use AVAssetImageGenerator

```
- (void)generateCGImagesAsynchronouslyForTimes:(NSArray *)requestedTimes completionHandler:(AVAssetImageGeneratorCompletionHandler)handler;
```

to generates the images. I did got the images, but the time of the image is not what I want.

request:{0/600 = 0.000, rounded} ,get:{0/600 = 0.000}

request:{110/600 = 0.183, rounded} ,get:{0/600 = 0.000}

request:{221/600 = 0.368, rounded} ,get:{0/600 = 0.000}

request:{331/600 = 0.552, rounded} ,get:{601/600 = 1.002}

request:{442/600 = 0.737, rounded} ,get:{601/600 = 1.002}

request:{552/600 = 0.920, rounded} ,get:{601/600 = 1.002}

request:{663/600 = 1.105, rounded} ,get:{601/600 = 1.002}

request:{773/600 = 1.288, rounded} ,get:{601/600 = 1.002}

request:{884/600 = 1.473, rounded} ,get:{601/600 = 1.002}

As you can see, the time are all rounded to integer，is there any to get exactly the second's image of the movie?

sorry for my poor English!
hope anyone can help me, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the answer in the [AVAssetImageGenerator Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAssetImageGenerator_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVAssetImageGenerator/requestedTimeToleranceAfter):

> Set the values of `requestedTimeToleranceBefore` and `requestedTimeToleranceAfter` to `kCMTimeZero` to request frame-accurate image generation; this may incur additional decoding delay.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
imageGenerator.requestedTimeToleranceAfter = kCMTimeZero;
imageGenerator.requestedTimeToleranceBefore = kCMTimeZero;
```